# Where are snowflake tables stored?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm considering snowflake for a customer, but I can't tell fr the documentation where do they store the data? Seems to be s3 but why such expensive storage costs? Is the data in the user's s3 or snowflakes s3?

Comment: Data would be stored in any of the cloud , AWS , GCP or Azure. Storing data is much cheaper then computing it. So the customer should not worry on storing data.

Comment: In short, you will only ever see your data through the Snowflake front end. You'll never be able to connect to the back end blobs directly. It's not the storage that costs the money, it's the compute.

Comment: Storage costs it's in the Bill.

Comment: https://www.snowflake.com/pricing/pricing-guide/

Comment: We have around ~80TB worth of data, and paying for about ~140TB worth of storage (timetravel/history days/churn). But the storage % of our bill is around the 15% mark. So in reality storage is almost ignorable.

Comment: Compared to s3 costs it's not free.

Comment: It's not most of the bill but it still high.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Snowflake is cloud based analytical data warehouse provided as Saas and it is not built on an existing database or “big data” software platform such as Hadoop and its available on below cloud environment

1. AWS
2. Azure
3. GCP

Based on the choice of your cloud environment your storage and computation region will be decided. If you selected snowflake on AWS, your data will be stored in snowflake managed S3 bucket(By default snowflake compress your data before it stores in your final target table), Its depends upon you and your business choice on which cloud your data should be stored.

Comment: So it's snowflake managed? You don't have access to it at all? What about when you cancel your account?

Comment: Yes, its fully managed by snowflake. If you want to cancel your snowflake account you have to reach out snowflake support team / raise case request to purge your data.